# extern const Array Declaration/Initialization Error (invalid initializer/conlficting types)

Tags: c, global-variables, declaration

For a project I'm working on, I want a statically-initialized, immutable, global array--specifically an array, *not* an `enum`.  To my knowledge, the best way to do this is with an `extern const` array.  However, when I try to initialize and declare any array `foo`, I get two different but apparently related compiler errors:

```
error: conflicting types for `foo'
error: invalid initializer
```

These are repeated for every initialization in the outer scope of my `.c` file.  The former of these errors  is always followed by a note reading "`` previous declaration of `foo' was here ``" and pointing to the declaration of the array in the header file.

In the following example...

```c
#ifndef __MWE__
#define __MWE__

extern const int foo[8];

#endif /* MWE */
```

```c
#include "mwe.h"
const int foo[0] = 0;
const int foo[1] = 42;
const int foo[2] = 69;
const int foo[3] = 420;
const int foo[4] = 9001;


int main(int argc,char**argv){return 0;}
```

...I get the following errors...

```
mwe.c:3:11: error: conflicting types for ‘foo’
 const int foo[0] = 0;
           ^~~
In file included from mwe.c:1:0:
mwe.h:4:18: note: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here
 extern const int foo[5];
                  ^~~
mwe.c:3:20: error: invalid initializer
 const int foo[0] = 0;
                    ^
mwe.c:4:11: error: conflicting types for ‘foo’
 const int foo[1] = 42;
           ^~~
In file included from mwe.c:1:0:
mwe.h:4:18: note: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here
 extern const int foo[5];
                  ^~~
mwe.c:4:20: error: invalid initializer
 const int foo[1] = 42;
                    ^~
mwe.c:5:11: error: conflicting types for ‘foo’
 const int foo[2] = 69;
           ^~~
In file included from mwe.c:1:0:
mwe.h:4:18: note: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here
 extern const int foo[5];
                  ^~~
mwe.c:5:20: error: invalid initializer
 const int foo[2] = 69;
                    ^~
mwe.c:6:11: error: conflicting types for ‘foo’
 const int foo[3] = 420;
           ^~~
In file included from mwe.c:1:0:
mwe.h:4:18: note: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here
 extern const int foo[5];
                  ^~~
mwe.c:6:20: error: invalid initializer
 const int foo[3] = 420;
                    ^~~
mwe.c:7:11: error: conflicting types for ‘foo’
 const int foo[4] = 9001;
           ^~~
In file included from mwe.c:1:0:
mwe.h:4:18: note: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here
 extern const int foo[5];
                  ^~~
mwe.c:7:20: error: invalid initializer
 const int foo[4] = 9001;
```

What is the proper way to declare and intialize `extern const` arrays, and what is it about this way that is invalid? Where is the type conflict, and why is an integer literal an invalid initializer for an element of an integer array?

Answer (score 0):

Each of these:

```
const int foo[0] = 0;
const int foo[1] = 42;
const int foo[2] = 69;
const int foo[3] = 420;
const int foo[4] = 9001;
```

Are separate definitions of an array variable named `foo`, each with a different size.  You're also trying to initialize these arrays with a single value.  That's why you're getting the errors.

If you want to initialize an array, you do so as follows:

```
const int foo[5] = { 0, 42, 69, 420, 9001 };
```

If you need to initialize particular indexes based on enum values, you can use designated initializers to do this:

```
enum {
    E1, E2, E3, E4, E5
};
const int foo[5] = { 
    [E1] = 0, 
    [E2] = 42, 
    [E3] = 69, 
    [E4] = 420, 
    [E5] = 9001 
};
```

Comment: This is less than optimal because it relies on the order of the literals.  In my actual project, I'm using `enum` subscripts.  Is it possible to symbolically reference individual cells of the array during initialization? If not, what options do I have other than an `extern const` array? I want the items to be static and global, and I want to be able to reference them symbolically, preferably by `enum`.

Comment: @FoobieBletch See my edit.  You can do this with designated initializers.

Comment: Given their use of designated initializers, they might leave the array length out of the definition and let the compiler figure it from the initializers. Depends on what they are doing.